# duplicate control rows by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set with a number of grouped treatments. In parallel in a couple of independent groups I collected a positive and negative control. For plotting purposes and further analysis I would like to duplicate the control groups for each individual treatment groups. So my plots turn from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

In dplyr, I have figured out how to identify and generate a column with the right control values, but the challenge is how to duplicate complete rows of the dataset and append them, rather than just adding a 'postive control' and 'negative control' column for each relevant groups. That approach kinda works, but means that you can really only store a summary value (e.g. mean) that gets copied across each treatment, rather than maintaing the individual readouts.

```
librar(ggplot)

before <- structure(list(group = c("grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", 
"grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", 
"neg", "neg", "pos", "pos"), treatment = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "none", "none", 
"none", "none"), value = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

ggplot(data = before, aes(x=treatment, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap (~group)

after <- structure(list(group = c("grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", 
"grp1", "grp1", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", 
"grp2", "grp2", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", 
"grp3", "grp3"), treatment = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "neg", "neg", 
"pos", "pos", "A", "B", "C", "D", "neg", "neg", "pos", "pos", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "neg", "neg", "pos", "pos"), value = c(3L, 
5L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

ggplot(data = after, aes(x=treatment, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap (~group)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to `filter` the rows with 'neg', 'pos' in `group` column and bind those with the `group_split` original data without the 'neg', 'pos' in `group` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
tmp <- before %>% 
          # // filter the rows where the group values are 'neg', 'pos'
          filter(group %in% c('neg', 'pos')) %>%
          # // then replace the treatment values with the group column values
          mutate(treatment = group) %>%
          # // remove the group
          select(-group)
```

Now we `filter` only the rows without the 'neg', 'pos' in the `group`

```
out <- before %>%  
     # // remove the rows where the 'neg' and 'pos' values are in group
     filter(!group %in% c('neg', 'pos')) %>%
     # // returns a list of data.frame/tibbles       
     group_split(group) %>% 
     # // loop over the list, then bind the data with the tmp data
     # // _dfr binds the list element as row binding
     map_dfr(~ bind_rows(.x, tmp) %>% 
                       # // As removed the group column in tmp
                       # // its values are NA
                       # // use fill to replace NA with non-NA previous value
                       fill(group))
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 24 x 3
#   group treatment value
#   <chr> <chr>     <int>
# 1 grp1  A             3
# 2 grp1  B             5
# 3 grp1  C             7
# 4 grp1  D             9
# 5 grp1  neg          12
# 6 grp1  neg          10
# 7 grp1  pos           1
# 8 grp1  pos           2
# 9 grp2  A             2
#10 grp2  B             4
# … with 14 more rows
```

Checking the plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = out, aes(x=treatment, y=value)) +
       geom_boxplot() + 
       facet_wrap (~group)
```

[image]

---

It can also be done in a single pipe

```
before %>% 
    # // replace the treatment values that 'none' with corresponding group values
    mutate(treatment = coalesce(na_if(treatment, 'none'), group)) %>% 
    # // do a group by group
    group_by( group) %>% 
    # // summarise the columns of interest with across
    summarise(across(c(treatment, value), 
      # // append the values in the full dataset where the group
      # // column is 'neg', 'pos'
      ~ c(., dplyr:::peek_mask()$full_data()[[cur_column()]][
          before$group %in% c("neg", "pos")])),
       .groups = 'drop') %>%
    # // filter out the 'pos', 'neg' group rows
    filter(!group %in% c('pos', 'neg'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 24 x 3
#   group treatment value
#   <chr> <chr>     <int>
# 1 grp1  A             3
# 2 grp1  B             5
# 3 grp1  C             7
# 4 grp1  D             9
# 5 grp1  neg          12
# 6 grp1  neg          10
# 7 grp1  pos           1
# 8 grp1  pos           2
# 9 grp2  A             2
#10 grp2  B             4
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. So to walk through, the tmp df is a split to remove the controls from the treatment groups and to have them handy to append. The we filter on everything that is not a pos/neg control and that's where things get a bit murky: The 'group_split' converts every group into individual lists? And then the map_dfr command uses a rbind-like command to append the tmp df to each of the split groups (`.x`)? And then `fill` reassembles everything? And assuming this is roughly right, would this work if there are additional grouping levels involved?

Comment: @MarioNiepel yes, it is just `filter`ing those rows iwth 'neg', 'pos' and append after splitting the filtered data without 'neg', 'pos' rows with the 'tmp

Comment: Sorry, I had submitted the comment by accident while I was still writing/editing.

Comment: @MarioNiepel I added some description in each line of code.  Hope itt helps you

Comment: You rock. That (and some judicious googling + trial&error) should get me though. Thank you!

Comment: unfortunately my  victory dance was premature. I kept the toy example simple, but now I am unclear on how to deal with real-life complexity. The 'group' in my example is actually only a single variable in a higher nested treatment scheme. For each group there are actually four additional grouping variables that need to be split out--all with their own respective pos/neg controls. I think the approach above lumps all of these categories together as one, but the process needs to work on a `by_group` level on all those variables in parallel. (And sorry if unclear. Will try and edit post.)

Comment: @MarioNiepel can you post as a new question as the nested condition will be different from the one you have

Comment: Will do. It’ll take me a bit to even think about posteing the right example. The actual data is confidential but I want to make sure I capture the complexity of the problem.

Comment: @MarioNiepel Thanks.  I also posted a second solution.  I hope you can try those as well

Comment: Hi @akrun, I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453438/propagating-controls-for-a-number-of-nested-groups/65457343 And I also got to a solution, based on and inspired by much of the info you provided here. It does rely on purrr, but the one step that really made it easy was using (full_join) to propagate the control values to each condition. And I still have a lot of work to do to really understand how to work with the various purrr functions...